# Pivoted pandas dataframe to dictionary conversion

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a pivoted pandas dataframe as shown in attachment.[image]

I need to convert these values into a dictionary which ignores the NaN values and gives me this:

col2_0 : 20000, col2_1 : 20000 col2_0 : 2000,col2_1 : 2000 col2_0 : 15000, cols_1 : 20000 col2_0 : 15000, col2_1 : 15000 col2_0 : 2000, col2_1 : 2000

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: But you can't have a dict with repeated keys. Do you mean to combine the col1 and col2 values for your keys?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
try: 
    dict[colon_number] = colon_value
except:
    None
```

But this won't work if `NaN` is a string, it is hard to say anything just from the image.